# Newline handling in python3 lark parser

Tags: python, parsing, lark-parser

I am using python(3.11.5) with lark-parser.

I am directly using the included python3 grammar, from https://github.com/lark-parser/lark/blob/master/lark/grammars/python.lark.

I am facing an issue in generating the parse tree for multiline dictionaries, or multiline function calls etc.
For example -

```py
data = {
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
    "city": "New York"
}
```

It gives the error - `Unexpected token Token('_NEWLINE', '\n    ')`

So my question is, how to take this into account? I have two ideas that I can think of -

- having a pre-processor before parsing, which can bring everything to single line.
- handling of newline in grammar.

Any other suggestions and explanations please.

Comment: Are you using the `PythonIndenter` postlexer? If used correctly, the grammar fully parsers Python code (before the changes in py1.12) with very few problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the correct Indenter class that fixes everything, from the same linked github repo.

```
class TreeIndenter(Indenter):
    NL_type = "_NEWLINE"
    OPEN_PAREN_types = ['LPAR', 'LSQB', 'LBRACE']
    CLOSE_PAREN_types = ['RPAR', 'RSQB', 'RBRACE']
    INDENT_type = "_INDENT"
    DEDENT_type = "_DEDENT"
    tab_len = 4
```